# generic term for "A-hed"? (quirky article at the bottom of the front page of the Wall Street Journal)

Tags: terminology

The Wall Street Journal usually has a quirky article on the bottom of the front page, on anything from paper clips to tugboat racing to borscht manufacturers. Their name for it is [an A-hed](http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424052702303362404575580494180594982.html). Is there a generic term for this? (I've seen a similar concept in other papers, on a less regular basis)

Comment: A generic term for a funny/exotic story? Or for the quirky story on the front page?

Comment: To be more specific, I would say: quirky article published by mainstream newsmedia, often with a specific location in print media.

Answer (score 7):

WSJ [claims](http://bayoubro.com/index_files/AboutFloating.htm) to have invented both the term and the technique, but you could call it a "general interest column". Or perhaps the "writers column" or "editors column". Some people simply describe it as a "middle column", but I don't know if that term describes the page formatting or the content of the A-hed.

Also, it's worth noting that "hed" [is shorthand for headline.](http://mediacareers.about.com/od/glossary/g/hed.htm)

Comment: I think you covered all three key parts: the WSJ created that particular version, the broader version is called a "general interest column", and that "A-hed" is a headline on the first (A) page. +1!

Comment: The term is probably true but I do have a few papers from the 1800's that have these human interest features as well.  So I doubt that the WSJ actually invented the technique.

Comment: I disagree that this question should be closed (appealing to readers of the WSJ is a pretty large basis). Here is a great article that mentions the origin of the "A" in "A-hed" (the shape of the headline): http://www.cjr.org/the_audit/a_quality_barometer_for_the_wa.php

Answer (score 0):

The term would be a [Feature](http://nie.brownsvilleherald.com/newspaperterms.htm).

Generically it could also be called a **Column**

Answer (score 0):

The term I would use to describe such a story is **pot pourri**, as it can refer to a variety of similar object collected together.

Comment: Why pot-pourri? What does an A-hed have in common with a fragrant collection of flowers?

Comment: @Eldross: Pot pourri can refer to a collection of THINGS as well as flowers. (At least it did on an American TV show called Jeopardy.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing this info into your answer. Feel free to reverse, or change further if you are not pleased with my change.